# Publish from 2 collections in Meteor (list each user that liked post)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

How can I query a collection for all users that "liked" **this** post and then put it in a template?

Collections:

```
likes: {
    "_id": 1234,
    "userId": "1dsaf8sd2",
    "postId": "123445"
}, {
    "_id": 1235,
    "userId": "23f4g4e4",
    "postId": "123445"
}

users: {
    "_id": 1 dsaf8sd2,
    "profile": {
        "name": "Bob",
        "details": "Cool sentence about Bob."
    }

}, {
    "_id": 23 f4g4e4,
    "profile": {
        "name": "Sam",
        "details": "Cool sentence about Sam."
    }

}
```

Publish:

```
Meteor.publish('likes', function(postSlug) {
    check(postSlug, Object);

    // find the post that matches slug and return its id
    var postId = Posts.findOne({
        slug: postSlug
    }, {
        _id: 1
    });

    // find all users that liked this post
    var data = Likes.find({
        postId: postId
    }).forEach(function(doc) {
        return Meteor.users.find({
            _id: doc.userId
        });
    });

    if (data) {
        return data;
    }
    return this.ready();
});
```

Helper for template:

```
Template.listLikers.helpers({
    likers: function(){
        return this;
    }
});
```

Now print out each result in template to list each liker of this post:

```
{{#each likers}}
    <h1>{{name}}</h1>
    <p>{{details}}</p>
    <a href="/profile/{{_id}}">See Full Profile</a>
{{/each}}
```

I feel I either have my collections structured wrong or my `forEach()` is problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem can be solved by using Mongo's `$in:` selector as follows:

```
Meteor.publish('likes', function (postSlug) {
  check(postSlug, Object);
  var postId = Posts.findOne({ slug: postSlug},{ _id: 1 }); // find post that matches slug

  var relatedLikes = Likes.find({ postId: postId },
    { fields: { userId: 1 }}).fetch(); // fetch the userId field from likes. _id will come with it

  var userIdArray = _.pluck(relatedLikes,'userId'); // extract just the userIds into an array
  return Meteor.users.find({ _id: { $in: userIdArray }});
});
```

Have you looked at [reywood:publish-composite](https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite)? It's excellent for collection joining problems such as this one.

Answer (score 0):

As [Michel Floyd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33514567/5107545) suggests, you could use the [`reywood:publish-composite`](https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite) package:

```
Meteor.publishComposite('likes', function (postSlug) {
    return {
        find: function () {
            return Posts.find({slug: postSlug});
        },
        children: [
            {
                find: function (post) {
                    return Likes.find({postId: post._id});
                },
                children: [
                    {
                        find: function (like) {
                            return Meteor.users.find({_id: like.userId});
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});
```